# Merging data frames stored in lists

Tags: r, list, merge

I have two lists. Every component in the lists is a data frame. The two lists are symmetric. They both contain data frames for years 2006-2012, just on different themes. I would like to merge the data frames ' horizontally' (that is the one of 2006 in the first list with that of 2006 in the second list, and so on) obtaining a third list of data frames. I tried to figure out how to do that with lapply, but there must be something I didn't understand about that function.

Could you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to understand what you want without an example. Recommend starting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe you need `do.call(cbind, List_of_data_frames)`, but without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's hard to figure out what you really need.

Comment: If you'd like to figure out what you don't understand it would be good to put up the code that didn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was so confused that I didn't manage to upload a piece of code that made sense to me. I had the feeling that this operation was possible by I couldn't really figure out how. I am a beginner user and need to completely figure out how to use lists and the functions that apply to them. Next time I'll try harder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `l3` in this code, you mean?

```
DT1 = data.frame(A=1:3,B=letters[1:3])
DT2 = data.frame(A=4:5,B=letters[4:5])
l1 = list(DT1,DT2)
DT1 = data.frame(A=1:3,C=letters[7:9])
DT2 = data.frame(A=4:5,C=letters[11:12])
l2 = list(DT1,DT2)

l3 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(l1))
for ( i in 1:length(l1))
{
l3[[i]]   <- merge(l2[[i]],l1[[i]], by = "A")
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also had in mind a for loop but I thought that it was possible (and parhaps more efficient) to do the job also with lapply. People always suggest that when dealing with lists. But thanks! I will follow your advice.

Comment: And @Riccardo, if this does answer your question then please considering clicking on the check mark next to the answer to consider it accepted.

Comment: In general `apply` and similar functions are much more efficient than `for` loops.  In this case, it probably doesn't matter.  See pg 46 of [this issue of R News](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2008-1.pdf) for more details and tips on how to make `for` loops as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Christopher thank you very much for specifying this.

Comment: This doesn't run... `Error in vector(mode = "list", length = length(l)) : object 'l' not found`

Comment: Thanks, @hedgedandlevered. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this is what you're after?

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = 2006, x = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(year = 2007, x = 4:6)
df3 <- data.frame(year = 2006, x = 7:9)
df4 <- data.frame(year = 2007, x = 10:12)

l1 <- list(x2006 = df1, x2007 = df2)
l2 <- list(x2006 = df3, x2007 = df4)

lapply(names(l1), function(x) cbind(l1[[x]], l2[[x]]))
####
[[1]]
  year x year x
1 2006 1 2006 7
2 2006 2 2006 8
3 2006 3 2006 9

[[2]]
  year x year  x
1 2007 4 2007 10
2 2007 5 2007 11
3 2007 6 2007 12
```

There may be other functions that would be more appropriate than `cbind()` such as `merge()`, but this should get you on the right path. This obviously assumes that you have named your lists and those names are consistent between `l1` and `l2`.

***EDITED TO ADD SOME MORE CONTEXT***

There are a few key assumptions that make this work. Those assumptions are:

1. Your list objects have `names`
2. The `names` in each list are consistent between lists

So, what are the `names` I'm referring to? If you look at the code about where I define `l1`, you'll see `x2006 = df1` and `x2007 = df2`. I'm defining two objects in that list, `df1` and `df2` with two names `x2006` and `x2007`.

You can check the names of the list by asking for the `names()`:

```
names(l1)
####
[1] "x2006" "x2007"
```

The other key assumption is that you can index objects in a list by their name, using the `[[` function. For example:

```
l1[["x2006"]]
####
  year x
1 2006 1
2 2006 2
3 2006 3
```

So what we're doing with the `lapply` function is that we're iterating over the names of `l1`, defining an anonymous function, and then using the `[[` function to index the two list objects `l1` and `l2`. We're currently using `cbind` as the function, but you can replace `cbind` with almost any other function.

As I mentioned above, this assumes that the `names` are the same between the two or more list objects. For example, this does not work:

```
#change the names of the l2 list
names(l2) <- c("foo", "bar")
lapply(names(l1), function(x) cbind(l1[[x]], l2[[x]]))
####
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
```

The `names` however do not have to be in the same order. That's where the benefit of the `[[` function comes in. To wit:

```
#Fix names on l2 again
names(l2) <- c("x2006", "x2007")
l2reverse <- list(x2007 = df4, x2006 = df3)

all.equal(
  lapply(names(l1), function(x) cbind(l1[[x]], l2[[x]])),  
  lapply(names(l1), function(x) cbind(l1[[x]], l2reverse[[x]]))
)
####
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain a bit more how you used lapply? In a very good programming manual I found a similar example to yours but didn't manage to understand it.

Comment: @Riccardo - added some more context and explanation for you.

Comment: Really kind of you to take the time to leave a clear explanation for me and other users. It is thanks to people like you that forums become powerful learning tools. I wish I had reputation above 15 to leave you a +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` might be of use here too.

Here's a third interpretation of what you might be asking for:

Some sample data:

```
DT1 <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=letters[1:3])
DT2 <- data.frame(A=4:5, C=letters[4:5])
l1 <- list(DT1,DT2)
DT1 <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=letters[7:9])
DT2 <- data.frame(A=4:5, C=letters[11:12])
l2 = list(DT1,DT2)
```

`merge` with `mapply`:

```
mapply(FUN=function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="A"), 
       l1, l2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
#   A B.x B.y
# 1 1   a   g
# 2 2   b   h
# 3 3   c   i
# 
# [[2]]
#   A C.x C.y
# 1 4   d   k
# 2 5   e   l
```

---

For reference....

Here's @Chase's interpretation of your question done with `mapply`:

```
mapply(cbind, l1, l2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# $x2006
#   year x year x
# 1 2006 1 2006 7
# 2 2006 2 2006 8
# 3 2006 3 2006 9
# 
# $x2007
#   year x year  x
# 1 2007 4 2007 10
# 2 2007 5 2007 11
# 3 2007 6 2007 12
```

Here's @Codoremifa's interpretation of your question done with `mapply`:

```
mapply(FUN=function(x, y) merge(x, y), 
       l1, l2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
#   A B C
# 1 1 a g
# 2 2 b h
# 3 3 c i
# 
# [[2]]
#   A B C
# 1 4 d k
# 2 5 e l
```

What would be more helpful is if you post some sample data and your expected output so that there is less guessing about what you're trying to do :-)

Comment: Wow @Ananda Mahto, great example! The first example with mapply is the one I was looking for. I will use it as a precious reference next times I will use lists. Many thanks.